# Banach algebras satisfying $pq=qp=q \Rightarrow \|q\|\leq\|p\|$ for all idempotents $p$ and $q$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras

This question could be way below the level of MO, so apologies in advance. I posted the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4500988/banach-algebras-satisfying-pq-qp-q-rightarrow-q-leq-p-for-all-idempote) in MS about 10 days ago without a definitive answer so far.

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra with the property $\hspace{4mm}q=pq=qp \Rightarrow \|q\|\leq \|p\|\hspace{4mm}$ whenever $p,q\in A$ are idempotents.

> Is there a term coined to the algebras with this property in the literature?

For example, $\ell^2$ with pointwise operations has this property, whereas its unitization $\ell^2\oplus\mathbb{C}$ does not.

---